# Is there a way to write a function in SQL, which will return a column that you can call in a select statement?

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, calculated-columns, table-valued-parameters

For example, I want to be able to write function 'f()' that I can call as written below.   (Note that @tbl is a user-defined memory table that I've previously created with columns Var1 and Var2, and that my function 'f' calls for a parameter of user-defined table type.)

```
SELECT t1.Var1, t1.Var2, f(@tbl) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Var1)
From @tbl as t1
```

It seems like user defined functions will either return table values or scalar values.  I need to be able to return a column though, because I want to apply the function over a given column by group.

Comment: What RDBMS are you working with? MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? It looks like it might be SQL Server but I want to be sure.

Comment: Assuming it's SQL Server, CROSS APPLY will most likely give you what you are looking for.

Comment: on what basis you want to select those column,after that what and why ?

Answer (score 0):

Scalar-Valued Function will give you column

Answer (score 0):

with Scalar Function

eg:

**1 create the function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[duplicate] (@number int)
returns double 
as
begin
 declare @duplicate double
 set @duplicate = @number * 2
 return @duplicate
end
```

/********/

**2 use the function**

We have a table "numbers" like:

**id | val**

1  | 2

2  | 5

3  | 3

then

```
select id, duplicate(val) as dup
from numbers
```

the result:

**id | dup**

1  | 4

2  | 10

3  | 6